# Chrome extension: open new tab as mobile device

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, let

I've made for myself a Chrome extension in order to perform automatically Bing Searches.
This code works perfectly.

I would like to extends this function adding the automatic search as mobile device (like when you enter in developer mode with F12).

I've searched a lot but I didn't find anything.
There is a way through api to force the browser to go in mobile mode? Like a parameter in `chrome.tab.update` or a header change?

Thanks.

```
async function doSearches() {
    let numberOfSearches = 100; 
    let words = [] // array of words. I simplified the code

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSearches; i++) {

        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)

        chrome.tabs.update({
            url: `https:www.bing.com/search?q=${words[randomNumber]}`
        })

        await timer(milliseconds)
    }

}
```

Comment: "I've searched a lot but I didn't find anything." --- That's not very specific... it helps to say what you've found that looked promising, but didn't answer your question. That said, have you looked at [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/)? Also... "searching a lot" apparently did not include SO: [Open an website in mobile mode in a new window on desktop chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547028/open-an-website-in-mobile-mode-in-a-new-window-on-desktop-chrome)

Comment: I don't find any options to open a tab in mobile mode with chrome.debugger